# Steam cannot be installed because of missing 32-bit libraries

Tags: software-installation, steam

Whenever I open Steam, it shows me this :

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
```

However, after I press Return, it shows me this :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  initscripts libc6 tzdata

Package libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgl1-mesa-dri

N: Ignoring file 'playonlinux.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'steam.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'webupd8team-ubuntu-java-xenial.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'otto-kesselgulasch-ubuntu-gimp-xenial.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'patches.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'nathan-renniewaldock-ubuntu-flux-xenial.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'mc3man-ubuntu-trusty-media-xenial.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'google.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'versable-ubuntu-elementary-update-xenial.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'elementary.list.disable' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-dri:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-glx:i386' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libc6:i386' has no installation candidate
Press return to continue:
```

after which an error stating "You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6" pops up.

I cannot find anyway to install these libs. Does anyone know how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Follow the bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1622391

Comment: OP did not report back additional info on the Launchpad thread nor the elementary StackExchange comments.

Answer (score 1):

One of [these](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233005) should do the trick. Test if it opens after each one and report back?

1. `sudo apt install steam`
2. `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386`
3. `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-dri:i386`
4. `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/libGL.so.1`
5. `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
   `sudo nano /etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf`
   opens a text editor, so insert these lines:
   `/usr/lib32`
   `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa`
   (save with ctrl+o and exit with ctrl+x)
   `sudo ldconfig`

(If 4/5/6 doesn't work by itself, cycle back through 1–3 again)

Comment: @wold The first line to install Steam returned this for me.

Comment: Unfortunately none of those worked :(. First line returned an error saying there are some unmet dependencies, whereas the other 2 lines had no installation candidate.

Comment: @Sanctimony: I just added 4 & 5. Try those and see if it works. Then try 1–3 again

Comment: Nope, didnt work :(. If it helps, I already had those two lines present in the text editor.

Comment: @Sanctimony, are you getting the same errors? Any new information? Was there anything else in the forum post I linked in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a fix, as I am a newb to linux, but I am also having issues installing steam. I got the same error, and I was able to resolve it by using the following command in terminal:

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 0):

I remove modded source.list and use backup.source.list (source.list.save).
Then i do

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
steam
```

and all problem was be fix, maybe its help you.

my source.list

```
#deb cdrom:[elementary OS 5.1 _hera_ - stable amd64 (20200706)]/ bionic contrib main non-free

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```